# Removing extra white space between paragraphs before a new section

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I'm happy with the space management that LaTeX applies to the documents. However, there are times when the next section cannot be included on the current page and goes to the next page. This makes the distance between previous paragrpahs disproportionately large.

Is there a command to avoid this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Since you did not include any background information about your code, I guess you are using a `twoside` documentclass. If that't the case, add `\raggedbottom` to your preamble.

Comment: Yes, i'm using the `twoside` class. It worked, thanks!!